# Can I just import Vue from "/path/to/vue.js" without npm/NodeJs involved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to get the web app from just the a single index.js file, through the `import` of the available files, like in the image:

[image]

With the outcome of: `import not found: default`

Are you forced to use Vuejs through `<script></script>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this without WebPack as well?

This should point you in the right direction

https://medium.com/@jamesweee/using-vue-js-single-file-component-without-module-bundlers-aea58d892ad9

Comment: Thanks figured out how to deal with this :D

Comment: figured out that I don't know how to pass data to the 'app-world' component from the `new Vue(...)`, do you know any clue on how to pass data to the `.vue` component?